Flipping letters along the axes of a Cartesian coordinate system
I need to illustrate how letters can be flipped within a Cartesian coordinate system along the x- and y-axis as shown in the image below.

It works perfectly fine with the code below, but I was wondering if there is a better way of doing it? Especially because the a in normal presentation (the first one) only shows up when I put it in a rotatebox, which is kind of pointless, as it’s not rotated.
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}

\title{Flipping letters in a coordinate system}



\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[very thin,color=gray!15,step=.5] (-2,-2) grid (2,2);
\draw[-latex] (-2,0) -- (2,0) node[right] {$\Large x$};
\draw[-latex] (0,-2) -- (0,2) node[above] {$\Large y$};


\filldraw[black] (1,.5) circle(0pt) node[above] {$\rotatebox{0}{\Huge a}$}; % shows only up if put in rotatebox
\filldraw[black] (1,-.5) circle(0pt) node[below] {$\reflectbox{\rotatebox{180}{\Huge a}}$};
\filldraw[black] (-1,-.5) circle(0pt) node[below] {$\rotatebox{180}{\Huge a}$};
\filldraw[black] (-1,.5) circle(0pt) node[above] {$\reflectbox{\Huge a}$};

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}


You can rotate and rotate around nodes just as well. You can also mirror them along an axis if needed.

With my ext.transformations.mirror library: \path[node font=\Huge, above, transform shape] foreach \mir in {, xmirror=0, ymirror=0, rotate=180}{[style/.expand once=\mir] node at (1, .5) {$a$}};

Thank you, that works nicely!

Though, in your simple case, you don't need that since xmirror=0 is the same as yscale=-1 and so on: \path[node font=\Huge, above, transform shape] foreach \mir in {, yscale=-1, xscale=-1, rotate=180}{[style/.expand once=\mir] node at (1, .5) {$a$}}; (And rotate=180 is just xscale=-1, yscale=-1.)

you don't need nested rotatebox and reflectbox, reflectbox is simly \scalebox{1}[-1] so you just need \scalebox with combinations of 1 and -1

Thank you both, it works fine with regular characters, but I’ve now run into a problem applying the same to a runic character: \path[node font=\Huge, above, transform shape] foreach \mir in {, xmirror=0, ymirror=0, rotate=180}{[style/.expand once=\mir] node at (1, .5) {$ᚱ$}};
Now the character doesn’t show up at all anymore. Any ideas why that might be?

Addition: I’m using the Junicode font for the whole document, so it’s definitely not that the font simply doesn’t have the character. Further, using the code from my example, runic characters show in the system, it’s once I try to apply the @Qrrbrbirlbel solutions that it stops working. I tried this and this, but neither works.
